# Waiting for <appname> to launch forever

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I can't run my program anymore in simulator or on iPhone.

It compiles just fine. No issue. But then I got the message

Waiting for  to launch

It happens forever.

[image]

This happen only in one project.

Answer (score 1):

I, finally got this thing solved by using backup of xproj file

The problem is in xproj file. However, I don't know what.

I am still waiting for better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with xcode, the solution was to open another project and then try again. Even reinstalling xcode wouldn't do the trick